# How to make ServiceStak service internal access only

Tags: .net, servicestack

I Want to make all services access internal only.
Is there any way to global set RestrictAttribute to affect all services ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to restrict all Services is to use a `GlobalRequestFilter`, e.g:

```
GlobalRequestFilters.Add((req, res, dto) => {
    if ((RequestAttributes.InternalNetworkAccess & req.RequestAttributes) == 0)
    {
        res.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.Forbidden;
        res.StatusDescription = "External Requests are Forbidden";
        res.EndRequest();
    }
});
```